# Attempt to read property "users_id" on null

Tags: laravel-8

I am facing this error:

> Attempt to read property "users_id" on null

in Laravel 8 controller.

```
public function editData88(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->with(['detail_data' => function ($query) {
            $query->with('agama');
        }])->first();
        $data_agama = Agama88::all();
        return view('crud.edit88', compact('user', 'data_agama', 'id'));
    }
```

Blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Alamat</label>
    @if ($user->id == $user->detail_data->users_id)
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamat" name="alamat"
            value="{{ $user->detail_data->alamat }}">
    @else
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamat" name="alamat"
            placeholder="Masukkan Alamat">
    @endif
</div>
```

Model

```
public function detail_data()
    {
        // return $this->belongsTo(detail_data::class);
        return $this->hasOne(Data88::class, "users_id", "id");
    }
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: The error is telling you that `detail_data` here is null: `$user->detail_data->users_id`.  So for the given user, there is no `detail_data`.  The obvious explanation is that is true - there are no `detail_data` records for that user.  Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a relation called agama? If not, you shouldn't use

> $query->with('agama');

From the available code, I suggest to try:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->with('detail_data')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming having no detail_data on a user isn't a bug you can change your if statement to this:

```
@if ($user->id == $user->detail_data?->users_id)
```

This way if you have no detail_data it will return null instead of trying to read user_id on null.